# Need to encrypt and decrypt using PEM key

Tags: c#, security, bouncycastle

Is it possible to use C# to encode a string of text using a .PEM file and decode it using the same .PEM file?

Answer (score 1):

If the PEM file contains the private key, the public key can be computed out of it so it is indeed possible to encrypt a text and then decrypt it again using that PEM file.

PEM is not supported by the c# framework, but third party libraries such as BouncyCastle can help you: http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/